# angular - Adding a class to a DOM element when clicked

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a class that will change its appearance (*e.g. burger to x*), to a menu trigger DOM element that has its own method to show an overlay menu, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is what I have so far - this is calling an external method for the menu itself:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutService } from 'app/core/services/layout.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'header-main',
    templateUrl: 'header-main.component.html',
})


export class HeaderMainComponent {

    @ViewChild('nav-trigger') el: ElementRef;

    constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService) { }

    menuToggle() {
        this.layoutService.mainMenuToggle();
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('opened');
    }
}
```

I am new to Angular 2. How is this supposed to work-out? Should I use the `Renderer` , why I should use the `Renderer`? And etc. questions

---

> EDIT: The issue with the absolute click event (selecting the child, not the parent) is that we have to use a **[reference tag](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)** paired with the `@ViewChild` decorator as so:

`@ViewChild('navTrigger') navTrigger: ElementRef;` which relates to the `#navTrigger` reference in the HTML template.

Therefore:

```
export class HeaderMainComponent {
    logoAlt = 'We Craft beautiful websites'; // Logo alt and title texts

    @ViewChild('navTrigger') navTrigger: ElementRef;

    constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    menuToggle(event: any) {
        this.layoutService.mainMenuToggle();
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.navTrigger.nativeElement, 'opened', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Tyler's answer, things have changed a bit. `Renderer` is depreciated and replaced by `Renderer2`. In `Renderer 2`, the class `setElementClass` is replaced by `addClass`. And the new function signature for `addClass`, according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) is

```
addClass(el: any, name: string): void
```

So the updated `menuToggle` function should read

```
menuToggle(event:any) {
    this.renderer.addClass(event.target,"opened");
}
```

Answer (score 18):

To accomplish what you want, you will need to use the Renderer(injecting it into the constructor with `private renderer: Renderer`).  The Renderer provides an abstraction over native elements and provides a safe way to interact with the DOM.

In your template, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div (click)="menuToggle($event)"></div>
```

This captures the click event and passes it to the `menuToggle` function.

Then in your component, you should be able to interact with the DOM using the Renderer like this:

```
menuToggle(event:any) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(event.target,"opened",true);
}
```

The function signature for `setElementClass`, according to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html#!#setElementClass-anchor) is `setElementClass(renderElement: any, className: string, isAdd: boolean) : void`

For further reading on the Renderer, [this is a good article on Medium](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-explore-the-renderer-service-e43ef673b26c#.dkn67xucg).  In talking about using the `ViewChild` and accessing the DOM through the `nativeElement` compared to using the `Renderer`, it says:

> This works fine(using nativeElement from a ViewChild). We are grabbing the input element with the help of
> the ViewChild decorator and then access the native DOM element and
> call the focus() method on the input.
>
> The problem with this approach
> is that when we access the native element directly we are giving up on
> Angular’s DOM abstraction and miss out on the opportunity to be able
> to execute also in none-DOM environments such as: native mobile,
> native desktop, web worker or server side rendering.
>
> Remember that
> Angular is a platform, and the browser is just one option for where we
> can render our app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mind-boggling precision on the answer. I have a small issue with this though, in the markup `<a (click)="menuToggle($event)" class="nav-trigger">
      <i class="icon icon-menu opened"></i>
    </a>` this is being added to the inner child element, not to the direct owner of the class. How can I fix this?

Comment: You might need to check to see what is the `target`.  Potentially the click event is being transferred from the `<i>` up to the parent `<a>`.  In that case, you might need to use something like `event.parent`.  I haven't tested that.  It's just a guess.  You could always debug it and see what options exist on `event` by using `console.log(event)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a backing field in the component then bind to ngClass and use a typescript expression to conditionally add the class to the element. Note a click event should be used to toggle the backing field. eg.

1. In component: `openedBool: boolean = false;`
2. And `toggleOpenedBool() { openedBool = !openedBool; }`
3. In template: `<div (click)="toggleOpenedBool()" [ngClass]="{'opened': openedBool}"></div>`