# Add or remove DOM classes with jQuery in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angular

I am migrating an AngularJS app to Angular 2+. How should I implement the below code in Angular 2+ in order to add or remove CSS classes to the DOM:

```js
link(scope, element, attrs) {
  let app = angular.element(document.querySelector('#app'))
  element.on('click', (event) => {
    if (app.hasClass('nav-collapsed-min')) {
      app.removeClass('nav-collapsed-min')
      this.collapseService.notify(false)
    } else {
      app.addClass('nav-collapsed-min')
      this.collapseService.notify(true)
    }
    return event.preventDefault()
  })
}
```

Comment: don't use `querySelector` or `jQuery` in your Angular 2, is not need and it might break your code if you want to use SSR later on. Take a look to this post https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02. Anyway, most of this cases where you just want to toggle class can be done with `ngClass` directive

Answer (score 0):

use ngClass in your html. eg:

```
<div [(ngClass)] = "{'your-class-name': condition}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to change the class of an object, you can use angular [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) 
directive like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44535593) or using [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) as part of an onClick method in the ts file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809572). Be aware that you have to use renderer2 and not renderer (which is deprecated).

[From angular document](https://angular.io/guide/security#avoid-direct-use-of-the-dom-apis):

"***Avoid direct use of the DOM APIs***
The built-in browser DOM APIs don't automatically protect you from security vulnerabilities. For example, document, the node available through ElementRef, and many third-party APIs contain unsafe methods. **Avoid directly interacting with the DOM and instead use Angular templates where possible.**"

Answer (score 0):

I finally use the `import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';`to manipulate my `DOM` and implement my function like this:

```
 link(scope?, element?, attrs?) {
   const app = this.document.querySelector('#app');
   if (app.classList.contains('nav-collapsed-min')) {
      app.classList.remove('nav-collapsed-min');
      this.collapseService.notify(false);
   } else {
      app.classList.add('nav-collapsed-min');
      this.collapseService.notify(true);
   }
 }
```

So that worked great for me.