# how do i change the background color of row on click in ag grid table

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I want to change the background color of a row in ag-grid table ,on click of the row

i have tried using the getRowStyle and getRowClass, but that seems to work when the table is loaded initially . So i tried with onrowClicked, but doesnt seem to work.

```
onRowClicked : row => {
        if (row.data.hasNewData) {
          return { background: '#ff9998 !important'};
        } else if (row.data.hasWrongData === 'Yes') {
          return { background: '#f5ff8b !important' };
        } else if (row.data.hasNoData) {
          return { background: '#acff93 !important' };
        }
      }
```

i want the row background color to change on click based on different data parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809368/angular-2-adding-a-class-to-a-dom-element-when-clicked

Comment: if you are in `ngFor` loop you can alternatively pass the element reference / template reference  `#row` on click and use the `element.classList.add("someClass"); `

Comment: you can use on blur event on your controller in ag grid

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to **getRowStyle** and trigger it manually with **refreshCells()** when clicking the row by consuming the **onRowClicked** event.

Also, in the **getRowStyle** callback, you need to use **node.isSelected()** property in order to detect whether or not the row/node is selected.

```
gridOptions.onRowClicked = function(params) {
  gridOptions.api.refreshCells({
    rowNodes: [params.node],
    force: true // skips change detection -> always refreshes the row
  })
}

gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
  if (params.node.isSelected()) {
    if (row.data.hasNewData) {
      return { background: '#ff9998 !important'};
    } else if (row.data.hasWrongData === 'Yes') {
      return { background: '#f5ff8b !important' };
    } else if (row.data.hasNoData) {
      return { background: '#acff93 !important' };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngFor* and then bind Some click event with the Row:

Html:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <th># Policy ID</th>
   <th>Policy name</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let policy of policies; let i = index " (click)="changeBackGroud(i)" >
     <div [ngClass]="{'myBackgroud' : row[i].selected}">
      <td>{{policy.id}}</td>
      <td>{{policy.name}}</td>
     </div>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Ts:
make an array equal to the no. of items you are iterating with along with the indices and a property "selected = false" initially.

```
row = policies;

// i is the index of selected item
changeBackGroud(i)
{
  row.forEach(function(element) {
      element.selected = false;
        });
  row[i].selected=true;
}
```

Css:

```
.myBackgroud
{
  backgroud:aqua; 
}
```

You can make adjustments to CSS accordingly;