# Angular - how to add class when receiving event in template

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to add class when receiving a click event in template

What I do is something like this:

```
<div
      #myDiv
      (click)="myDiv.classList.add('my-class')"
></div>
```

but this does not work.

How can I make it works? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular - Adding a class to a DOM element when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809368/angular-adding-a-class-to-a-dom-element-when-clicked)

Comment: I would like to perform the code in html template. not inside component script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<div [ngClass]="classStr"
      (click)="classStr='my-class'">
</div>
```

you will have to add `classStr` to your component (just declare it - `classStr: string;` inside the component)

notice that this will only add the class once, not toggle it, if you want to toggle, you will have to do something like:

```
<div [ngClass]="classStr"
   (click)="classStr = classStr === 'my-class' ? '' : 'my-class' ">
</div>
```

Comment: so no way to bypass adding code inside component?

Comment: nope, not possible today, why is that a problem for you?